# Submit options from "select" tag in a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I saw a bunch of similar questions but I didn't figure out how to do this in my situation.

I have my **question** model, where one question can have many question dependencies. **question_dependency** is another model, where I save the type of dependency between two questions. So my form show a couple of questions to the user define the dependencies. It is the following:

```
<%= form_for [@exercise, @question] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Pontuação" %>
    <%= f.number_field :score, min: 0 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Descrição" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="box-body">
    <a style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dependencies">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Dependências
    </a>

    <div id="dependencies" class="collapse">
      <table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 60%">
        <tbody>
          <% @questions.each do |question| %>
            <tr>
              <%= f.fields_for :dependencies do |ff| %>
                <td>
                    <%= truncate(question.description, length: 50,
                                                       separator: " ") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" style="width: 80px">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>AND</option>
                    <option>OR</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              <% end %>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I submit this "dependency data" to my controller?

Comment: Whoever who answered before (and deleted after), thanks. Despite the php code, I learned the trick using the name property in the `select` tag. I believe there is a cleanest answer to my problem, but I can use this for now.